# Package polyglossia Error: I cannot switch `:' on or off--not a shorthand

Tags: polyglossia, bibleref

I updated Mactex 2018 today and got a polyglossia error from then on.
(Package polyglossia Error: I cannot switch `:' on or off--not a shorthand.)

There where no changes in the document... Is there a problem with polyglossia?

Update: Thanks for the help. I restored the old bibleref version and everything works well.

```
%!TEX TS-program = Xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,pagesize=auto,ngerman,greek,hebrew,english,russian,latin,bibliography=totocnumbered,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{bibleref-german}
\biblerefstyle{TRE} 
\biblerefformat{kurz} 
\usepackage[comma=chvsep]{bibleref-parse} 
\newcommand{\bible}[1]{\pibibleverse{#1}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\sloppy 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{ngerman}
\usepackage{bidi}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\setmainfont[%
Mapping=tex-text,%
Script=Latin%
]{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
Bla Bla. \bible{Mk10,51} zum Beispiel\ldots\ Package polyglossia Error: I cannot switch `:' on or off--not a shorthand.
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: There was a change in `biblref` a few days ago: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-July/007018.html That probably caused it. I have not updated my distribution and can't reproduce the error before the update. I'll make the update and report back.

Comment: BTW: You don't want `\setmainlanguage` and `\setdefaultlanguage`, you can only have one. Instead of `\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{ngerman}` you want `\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}`. `polyglossia` does not use `babel` names for language variants. `xunicode` is normally not needed any more and `\sloppy` as a global setting in the preamble seems like a bad idea. Your global options `ngerman,greek,hebrew,english,russian,latin` also don't do a lot at the moment - they are not picked up by `polyglossia`.

Comment: Yup, after an update to the newest `bibleref` I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Here is a shorter MWE that shows that the error is unrelated to `polyglossia` specifically. It is a general `babel`/`polyglossia` problem and happens for all languages for which `:` is not active: `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bibleref}

\begin{document}
\bibleverse{Gen}
\end{document}`

Comment: @moewe: Imho the problem is that bibleverse uses `\shorthandoff:` without actually checking if `:` is a shorthand or not.

Comment: Indeed, I thought  babel will do the test for myself and won't send any error, but just a warning. I will release soon a new version of bibleref.

Comment: @Maïeul actually it is an interesting question. I think one should ask Javier if there can be (or perhaps already is) a better interface for packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not sur to see your point.

Comment: @Maïeul well what you want is to "deactivate :" and later on "reactivate it, if it was active". So a sort of "push and pop" of catcodes. There are lots of packages who do this internally to, and I was wondering about a sensible interface. In any case: you shouln't make (like with your \shorthandon the colon active without checking if it was active at the begin of the command.)

Comment: The point is that the handbook of babel tell that shorthandoff "Both commands
only work on ‘known’ shorthand characters. If a character is not known to be a shorthand
character its category code will be left unchanged.". So, the test about the actual catcode is done in any case. The only point is that it produce an error and not just a warning

Comment: in any case, the version 1.20 of bibleref will do the test, and @C-P problem will be solved

Comment: I'll take note of this.